# How to set the file multiple file upload field as an Optional field in FastAPI? UploadFile

Tags: image, file, fastapi

My code:
SCHEMAS:

```
class PostShemas(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    image: Optional[Union[UploadFile, List[UploadFile]]] = File(None)
```

ROUTER:

```
@router.post('/add_post')
async def add_post(new_post: PostShemas = Depends(), session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session),
                   current_user=Depends(get_current_user)):
    # try:
        print(new_post.image)
        stmt = insert(Post).values(title=new_post.title, content=new_post.content,
                                   author_id=current_user.id)
        result_id = await session.execute(stmt)
        result_id = result_id.inserted_primary_key[0]
        if new_post.image:
            for index, element in enumerate(new_post.image):
                filename = generate_filename(new_post.image[index].filename)
                save_photo(filename, new_post.image[index].file)
                stmt = insert(Image).values(filename=filename, post_id=result_id)
                await session.execute(stmt)
        await session.commit()
        return {'status': 200, 'data': 1212}
```

The problem is that I can't transfer the file, as there is only a test field in swagger

I've already tried a lot of ways, it will take about 5 hours. I tried the following:

```
class PostShemas(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    image: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None)
```

Not working. I think the problem lies in the dependency in the API itself, but I can't solve it yet.